# Generating reports using PPS-SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, performancepoint

> Hi All,
>
> I need to generate some reports (bar graphs, pie charts etc) using
>   Performance Point Service in SharePoint 2010. I am able to generate
>   reports.
>
> I am facing issue when I am supposed to do some calculation and then
>   show values in these charts e.g.) get marks1 and marks2 and show
>   division(marks1/marks2) as one axis on graph.
>
> As we create these graphs we don't a provision of doing
>   calculations(We have measure and dimension to drag and drop).
>
> Please guide.
>
> Vikrant Raj Behal

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to have some columns in a PerformancePoint chart that need to be dynamically calculated.

This is not possible with PerformancePoint charts using the drag and drop capabilities. Depending on your needs you may be able to do some calculations or aggregates if you edit the MDX Query itself. However this may limit your drill down ability.

The other option is to do those calculations inside of your cube in the form of a calculated measure, then you could use the drag and drop functionality.

Here is [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f1923501-6fdd-4115-967d-ca08a9180623/grand-total-field-in-analytic-grid-report) to someone on technet whom asked a similar question